# Table view does not exist exception on Netbeans Derby connection

Tags: java, netbeans, derby, embedded-database

I followed the instructions [in this blog](http://aparna-java.blogspot.in/2011/11/good-day-all.html) to create a basic embedded database application.However, although checking the steps over and over and searching for the problem on the web , I'm still getting the exception : Table view blabla does not exists. Table seems to exists when I expand my driver's app schema. Netbeans version is 7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason for a table-does-not-exist error with Derby is confusion over the location of the database. The database that you are accessing via Netbeans is probably different than the database that your application is accessing.

The location of your database is controlled by the JDBC connection URL, so if you provide some details about your JDBC connection URL, that might help others to help you.

Comment: I have a very similar problem. Would you like to see the contents and details of my scenario. Would very much appreciate if you do

Comment: For some other common causes of table-does-not-exist, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996818/is-it-necessary-to-create-tables-each-time-you-connect-the-derby-database/23051822#23051822

Comment: **1.** I edited and removed the `create=true` option from the connection url
**2.** The localhost connection to the database is `closed`. I did not start the server.
**3.** I am connecting to the database with `app` for both `username and password` and I also selected APP as the default schema.

**Still the problem exists**

Comment: I would be very thankful if you just point me out where am I going wrong. I have mentioned the initial details regarding the schema and DB