# SQL Exception: Table does not exist when accessed using SOAP service

Tags: sql, soap, derby

I am using Derby database in embedded mode. I have written a CreateDB class with main() function that creates/inserts/select in a table. Works fine.(I have necessary jar files in project build path:) )

But, when i use same database and table to select rows in my Soap webservice, it gives me error that table doesn't exist. here is the code:
For CreateDB (Works Perfectly fine)

```
package com.myShop.www.ShipmentService;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class CreateDB {
public static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:Shipment_DB;create=true"; 
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
    String SQLString = "CREATE TABLE SHPMTTYPAV_TBL1(" +
            "SHPMTID INT NOT NULL, " +
            "NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, " +
            "DESCR VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, " +
            "MINCOST DOUBLE NOT NULL, " +
            "COSTPEROUNCE DOUBLE NOT NULL, " +
            "ESTDLVYDAYS INT NOT NULL, " +
            "PRIMARY KEY(SHPMTID))";

    connection.createStatement().execute((SQLString));
    String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO SHPMTTYPAV_TBL1 VALUES(5, 'Priority Mail', 'Any item can be shipped', 5, .02, 1)";
    connection.createStatement().execute(insertSQL);

    // invoke sql query
    String selectSQL = "SELECT * From SHPMTTYPAV_TBL1";

    Statement prepStmt = connection.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);
    while (rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getInt("SHPMTID") + rs.getString("NAME") + rs.getString("DESCR") + rs.getDouble("MINCOST") + " " + rs.getDouble("COSTPEROUNCE")); 
    }
}
}
```

Code in SOAP service Implementation class: - Error of Table not found

```
public class ShipmentServiceBindingImpl implements ShipmentServicePortType{
public static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:Shipment_DB;create=true";
public com.myShop.www.ShipmentService.ItemsInOrderResponseType[] getShpmtTps_Csts_DlvyDts(com.myShop.www.ShipmentService.ItemsInOrderType[] itemsInOrder) throws java.rmi.RemoteException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);

    String selectSQL = "SELECT * From SHPMTTYPAV_TBL1";

    Statement prepStmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);

    int len = itemsInOrder.length;
    ItemsInOrderResponseType[] res = new ItemsInOrderResponseType[len];


    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        rs.next();
        res[i] = new ItemsInOrderResponseType();
        res[i].setShpmtID(rs.getInt("SHPMTID"));
        res[i].setShpmtName(rs.getString("NAME"));
        res[i].setCost(rs.getDouble("COSTPEROUNCE"));
        res[i].setEstDlvyDays(rs.getDouble("MINCOST"));
    }
    if (rs != null) rs.close();
    if (prepStmt != null) prepStmt.close();
    if (connection != null) connection.close();
    return res;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try setting derby.system.home to the same value in both cases. If unset Derby uses the current directory which is likely different in the two cases.

Comment: Here are several other common reasons for "table does not exist": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996818/is-it-necessary-to-create-tables-each-time-you-connect-the-derby-database/23051822#23051822