# SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View does not exist

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I'm getting a large stack trace which at its root is caused by: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'U' does not exist.` Followed by an exception for everything that requires the entity: `java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Constraint 'PSSVSERSRDTABASEID' is invalid: referenced table U does not exist.`

I looked at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996818/is-it-necessary-to-create-tables-each-time-you-connect-the-derby-database/23051822#23051822) about a similar issue but it doesn't seem to address my particular problem. The reason being is when I open `Database Development` mode in Eclipse, I can see every other entity being mapped to a table, yet, not the entity User('U').

The User entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "disc", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name = "U")
@NamedQuery(name = "FIND_WITH_USER_ID", query="SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u WHERE u.userId = :userId")
public class User implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2468889149889625824L;
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    protected long databaseId;

    //getters/setters/etc

}
```

User does have a subclass (which shows up in the table schema):

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends User{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5239293307816318553L;

    public Customer(){
        super();
    } 

    //getters/setters/etc

}
```

In my persistence.xml file, I do specify for the tables to be created if they don't already exist:

```
<properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="C:\Program Files\GlassFish\glassfish-4.1\glassfish4\javadb\lib\derby.jar"></property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/AppDB;create=true"></property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
</properties>
```

As stated, other tables are shown in the database schema (and pings to the database succeed). The problem seems to form around the User entity. I thought it might have had something to do with reserved keyword name clashes, so I changed the name of the table a few times (there seems to be a problem with Eclipse/Glassfish once I encounter this exception, even if I make changes, such as the name, and relaunch the app it doesn't update; out of scope of question I believe).

**Why isn't a table being created for entity User?** What am I missing? Why are the other tables being created still?

Comment: The word "user" is a reserved word in ANSI Standard SQL and so to use it with Derby you have to enclose it in double quotes (a.k.a. delimited identifiers). Perhaps your object/relational tool is not completely quoting the word User when issuing SQL to Derby. Can you use a different name than "user"?

Comment: @Tiny obviously the table is not present! My question was: **Why isn't a table being created for entity User?**. The entity name is User, the corresponding table is named U. I have configured it to create the tables on start-up (persistence.xml file). All other tables are created (stated in question) except for the User (table name 'U').

Comment: @BryanPendleton yes I know the word "user" is a reserved word, hence the `@table(name = "U") annotation`. This changes the table name so the persistence provider will map the entity to table U. The class name User should have nothing to do with the mapping since I specified the `table` annotation. I believe my error lies somewhere else with the persistence provider. I'm just not sure where.

Comment: What if you replace `<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />` with `<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />` ?

Comment: Run your Derby with '-Dderby.language.logStatementText=true', and then look in your derby.log file to see what SQL statements are being issued to Derby, and what errors are being returned.

Comment: @wypieprz I've since added the `<propery name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>` line to my persistence file, unfortunately, with no effect.

Comment: @BryanPendleton I will give the 'logStatementText=true' a try. Do you know of anyway I can use the command with Eclipse? Or is it only possible via the command line?

Answer (score -1):

Problem is with you SQL script, you are passing the table alias name instead of column name. it should be u.

SELECT DISTINCT e.emp_id FROM Emp e

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you speaking about the NamedQuery I have specified on the Entity? If so, it's a valid JPQL statement.

Comment: I have faced the same problem and the reason was alias of the table name. In you case you have defined it as ":U"
try this
SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User as  u WHERE u.userId = :userId

Comment: It has nothing to do with the query statement. I receive the error on application start-up. The @NamedQuery is there for later use if I ever want to get a user instance and is correct the way it is.

Comment: Also, in JPQL, the as clause is optional, so, your statement is exactly the same as my NamedQuery statement (which, once again, is not the cause of the problem).