# Derby DB: Table/View doesn't exist ERROR 42X05

Tags: jdbc, derby

1. I installed a Derby DB and I opened a connection named "MyDbTest".
2. I created a table named BOOK for "MyDbTest" connection by the SQL command:

   CREATE TABLE BOOK(ID INT, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(20), UNITCOST VARCHAR(20), ISBN VARCHAR(20), NBOFPAGES INT);
3. I ran the Derby server by using the command: "startNetworkServer.bat"
4. I ran the following code (using Open JPA):

public class Main {

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("\n\n>>> Executing : " + Main.class.toString() + " <<<\n");    
        persistBook(new Book(new Long(5000), "H2G2", "Best IT Scifi Book", new Float(12.5), "1234-5678-5678",
                new Integer(247)));    
        Book book = findBook(new Long(5000));    
       System.out.println("# " + book);
  }

  /**
   * Gets a database connection
   */
  static {
    try {
      Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDbTest;create=true", "app", "app");
  }

  /**
   * Persists the book to the database
   */
  private static void persistBook(Book book) throws SQLException {

    String query = "INSERT INTO BOOK (ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, UNITCOST, ISBN, NBOFPAGE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    try (PreparedStatement stmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(query)) {

            stmt.setLong(1, book.getId().longValue());
      stmt.setString(2, book.getTitle());
      stmt.setString(3, book.getDescription());
            stmt.setFloat(4, book.getUnitCost().longValue());
      stmt.setString(5, book.getIsbn());
            stmt.setInt(6, book.getNbOfPage().intValue());

      stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
  }
}
```

and I got an Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Table/View 'BOOK' does not exist.
>   Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'BOOK' does not exist.

I also read the solution proposed in this post: [Is it necessary to create tables each time you connect the derby database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996818/is-it-necessary-to-create-tables-each-time-you-connect-the-derby-database).
Unfortunately, none of them helped me.

1. I changed "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDbTest;create=true" to "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDbTest;create=false"
2. I don't use "in-memory" configuration in Derby.
3. I don't think I connect to the DB as another user (I'm not sure about it. How can I check it?).

Comment: The process that you're going through to create the table is not clear. So hard to say. Maybe your program isn't connecting to the same db? Maybe different users and/or schemas?

Comment: I thought about it. I typed in ij shell: 
"show connections" and I got:

CONNECTION0* -  jdbc:derby:MyDbTest
* = current connection

Comment: Also, there's no JPA in the code. It's just JDBC. On top of that, the code doesn't close the database connection. That should be fixed.

Comment: OK. Can you propose code that will close the DB ?

Comment: 3 common reasons for "table does not exist" in Derby: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996818/is-it-necessary-to-create-tables-each-time-you-connect-the-derby-database/23051822#23051822

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to create tables each time you connect the derby database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996818/is-it-necessary-to-create-tables-each-time-you-connect-the-derby-database)

Comment: I read it. It didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because I was using the database name in the SELECT statement instead of the name of the table.